# JPA EclipseLink: How to Listen to Mysql Server changes in rows and data

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa

I have remote MySQL server and
Java Application that connected to this server  from other hosts 
This application works as multiple client connected to this server

My Question is how to make any Java Application client notify and changes its UI 
according to any changes can happen to this server from any other clients connected to this server.

Comment: This is a really broad question. You should most likely try to make sure that the other clients do some kind of notification when they're modifying data.

Comment: And how to do this !!!

Comment: With the skill and experience brought on by years of programming...